# AngularJS Collapse Expanded ng-Repeat item on Expand of another

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I understand complex ideas behind expanding and collapsing div's using AngularJS to some extent not all. So I know how to ng-repeat and expand/collapse within the ng-repeat the multiple objects and their values etc. What I'm having issues is if I have one item already expanded in an ng-repeat and I click to expand another, I want the one that was currently expanded to automatically collapse when the new one is expanded. Also I should be able to click expand/ collapse on the same item without issue as well. I'm running into a wall and I tried to scratch up an idea of what it is I'm doing. My actual work is working via collapsing and expanding, just the only thing I cannot get is to have one item collapse once I expand another.

So for example from the scratch code I provided below:

VA <- will be expand/ collaspe (on expand two cities show with the ability to expand/ collapse)

(on Expand of VA)

```
Virginia Beach
Richmond <- I expand Richmond then
```

Now I want to expand Virginia Beach, the minute I do this Richmond collapses and Virginia Beach Expands

The same idea will be applied to the states, the minute I expand TX, VA must collapse.

This is what I need help understanding.

Concept idea:

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="place in data">
    <h4 class="">{{place.state}}</h4>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="{{place.state}}.expanded=!{{place.state}}.expanded)">
      <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': {{place.state}}.expanded, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !{{place.state}}.expanded }"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="" ng-hide="{{place.state}}.expanded">
      <table class="">
        <thead>
          <tr class="">
            <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{place.value}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="" ng-repeat="city in data.city">
      <h4 class="">{{city.cName}}</h4>
      <button class="btn" ng-click="city.expanded=!city.expanded)">
        <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': city.expanded, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !city.expanded }"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="" ng-hide="city.expanded">
        <table class="">
          <thead>
            <tr class="">
              <th>Population</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{{city.pop}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Test data JSON:

```
    $scope.data = [{
    "state": "VA",
    "value": '14',
    "city": [{
      "cName": 'Virginia Beach',
      "pop": '650,000'
    }, {
      "cName": 'Richmond',
      "pop": '850,000'
    }]
  }, {
    "state": "TX",
    "value": '31',
    "city": [{
      "cName": 'Austin',
      "pop": '990,000'
    }, {
      "cName": 'Houston',
      "pop": '1,450,000'
    }]
  }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first things first:
when using ng-click, ng-show, or really any ng-attribute you don't use the {{}} - the values will automatically be interpreted properly.

So you don't want to write

```
   ng-click="{{place.state}}.expanded=!{{place.state}}.expanded)"
```

But rather (there was an extra ")" at the end)

```
 ng-click="place.state.expanded= !place.state.expanded"
```

Also - you use an ng-repeat which is great - however - in your ng-click you try to set the property on a String ... that won't work. Instead you should be setting the property on "place"

```
 ng-click="place.expanded= !place.expanded"
```

Those changes will give you expand/collapse behavior. To accomplish what you want I suggest you add a function that manages your collapse/expand behavior.
The basic idea is that you "remember" what they expand - so then you can "collapse" the element that was previously expanded. Alternatively you could also just iterate over your JSON data object and reset all values to collapsed (if you have a LOT of data you probably shouldn't do this.

Here's a quick Plunker that accomplishes what you want: https://plnkr.co/edit/NRInXUJvMZh3ah588WyY?p=preview

The basic idea is that  there are two scope variables, one for state that was expanded and one for the city that was expanded. If a user clicks on a state, the state that was expanded is collapsed, the clicked on state is expanded ... same for the city.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! Also thank you for properly explaining the property settings more to me. I'm not at an expert at this and you cleared up some of my issues.